# My Data being fetched from a nodejs server is empty and shows no results

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, sequelize.js

So im trying to fetch data from my nodejs server which im able to do but once I set the state in my front-end and I console log the Data, it shows that i just have an empty array and no data fetched my from my api

This is my Nodejs code

```
router.get('/information',(req,res)=>{
 User.findAll()
.then(data=>{
  console.log(data)
  res.json({data:data})
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

})

This is my React Code

```
class Dashboard extends Component{
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={
       results:[]
    }
}

  componentDidMount(){
      axios.get('http://localhost:4000/information')
      .then((data)=>{
          this.setState({
             results:[{...data}] 
          })
      })
  }
```

Comment: Try just returning `res.json(data)`

Comment: You can use `console.log(data)` to see what you got in your component.

Comment: @doublesharp i tried that and still nothing